# Roblox Studio- attempt to index nil with 'leaderstats' error in output

Tags: game-development, roblox

so i want to make this so when i click it gives me a "Coin" but it does not work & says attempt to index nil with 'leaderstats'

```
`game.Players.PlayerAdded:Connect(function(player)
local leaderstats = Instance.new('Folder', player)
leaderstats.Name = 'leaderstats'

local coins = Instance.new('IntValue', leaderstats)
coins.Name = 'Coins'
coins.Value = 0
end)


game.ReplicatedStorage.Remotes.Add.OnServerEvent:Connect(function()
local currency = 'Coins'
local amount = 5
player.leaderstats[currency].Value = player.leaderstats[currency].Value + amount
end)``
```

Answer (score 1):

You forgot the "player" parameter in [OnServerEvent](https://developer.roblox.com/en-us/api-reference/event/RemoteEvent/OnServerEvent#:%7E:text=Player-,The,associated%20with%20the%20client%20that%20the%20FireServer%20call%20originates%20from.,-arguments) which is why it's nil

fix:

```lua
game.ReplicatedStorage.Remotes.Add.OnServerEvent:Connect(function(player) --added player parameter
local currency = 'Coins'
local amount = 5
player.leaderstats[currency].Value = player.leaderstats[currency].Value + amount
end)
```